Removing final Exchange server, unable to follow Microsoft instructions
I'm reviewing the process to remove the last Exchange server in an environment by following Microsoft's instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/manage-hybrid-exchange-recipients-with-management-tools#permanently-shutting-down-your-last-exchange-server. Step 5 of "Permanently shutting down your last Exchange Server" is to remove the service principal credentials created for OAuth. It provides some PowerShell commands to determine and delete the credentials:

5a. Run these commands in the Exchange Management Shell to get the OAuth credValue:
$thumbprint = (Get-AuthConfig).CurrentCertificateThumbprint
$oAuthCert = (dir Cert:\LocalMachine\My) | where {$_.Thumbprint -match $thumbprint}
$certType = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Cert
$certBytes = $oAuthCert.Export($certType)
$credValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($certBytes)

5b. Find the KeyId that is same as the $credValue found above, run the
following commands as a tenant admin using Microsoft Graph PowerShell.
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Applications
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Application.Read.All"
$ServiceName = "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000"
$p = Get-MgServicePrincipalByAppId -AppId $ServiceName
$keyId = (Get-MgServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalId $p.Id).KeyCredentials $true | ?{$_.Value -eq $credValue}).KeyId

This gives the KeyId of the key whose value matches the $credValue
found above.
5c. To remove the service principal credential, run the following command:
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Applications
$params = @{
  KeyId = $keyId
}
Remove-MgServicePrincipalKey -ServicePrincipalId $p.Id -BodyParameter $params


That last $keyId assignment in 5b is not a valid PowerShell command, there is a "$true" that is out of place and there is an extra ending parenthesis. It looks like the command got corrupted. Running Get-MgServicePrincipal manually does return a KeyCredentials object but I don't see a "Value" property that it appears to be looking for. This might just be because part of the command is missing.
Does anyone know how I can complete this step? Either thru working PowerShell or other method such as the M365 portal? Also would skipping this step also be ok, understanding it may leave crud behind?

I had the same issue as you and found this searching for an answer.
Looking at the page in the wayback machine, the offending section used to read:
Connect-MsolService 
$ServiceName = "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000" 
$p = Get-MsolServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalName $ServiceName 
$keyId = (Get-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $p.AppPrincipalId -ReturnKeyValues $true | ?{$_.Value -eq $credValue}).KeyId


Great catch! That works here.
It looks like Microsoft attempted to convert it to use MSGraph (which is good) but best I can tell, Graph doesn't return any cert values. Even checking the underlining https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals(appId='{00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000}') graph call doesn't return any key values.

I have just tested this with another customer where I am removing their last exchange server. The Get-MsolServicePrincipalCredential did not return a keyid this time.
